# how to run a script while afplay is running

Tags: xcode, bash, applescript, applescript-objc

Hello everyone I am wondering how to continue with the script execution while afplay is running? For example...

```
   do shell script "afplay /song.mp3"
    say "Hello, nice to meet you, what's your name?"
```

When I execute the code the command "Say" won't be executed until the song stops!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
command_name &
echo "message"
```

the ampersand will run that command in the background.

So in applescript, something like this:

```
do shell script "afplay /song.mp3 &"
  "echo 'Hello, nice to meet you, what's your name?'"
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Purr.aiff & say Hello, nice to meet you, whats your name?"
```

I just tested this in AppleScript under OS X 10.8.3 and it works as you want.

Note that I removed the `'` from "what's".